# Run com.google.example.games.bc and fails

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I try to run the `ButtonClick` example of google, and I get this exception:

```
10-12 15:50:22.744    7085-7085/com.google.example.games.bc E/﹕ Device driver API match
    Device driver API version: 23
    User space API version: 23
10-12 15:50:22.744    7085-7085/com.google.example.games.bc E/﹕ mali: REVISION=Linux-r3p2-01rel3 BUILD_DATE=Wed Oct  9 21:05:57 KST 2013
10-12 15:50:23.049    7085-7085/com.google.example.games.bc E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: A fatal developer error has occurred. Check the logs for further information.
            at com.google.android.gms.internal.id$h.b(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.internal.id$h.e(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.internal.id$b.fv(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.internal.id$a.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I changed nothing from the [Git project](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples) (by Google).

Any clue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Check the logs for further information" - can you paste the logs?

Comment: Where's the log?? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it!

In the `AndroidManifest.xml` there is a **ReplaceMe** tag in:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
            android:value="ReplaceMe" />
```

There in `strings.xml` there is a `string` resource:

```
<string name="app_id">ReplaceMe</string>
```

Should replace the **ReplaceMe** :) with the `app ID` from the `google play console`.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to pay `google play console`, you can set `<string name="app_id">1</string>` in `strings.xml`